# Speech analyze / verification when reading a script

Tags: speech-recognition, voice, speech, voice-recognition

I need to programmatically analyze recorded voices that reads a known script. The output should tell me where (in time coordinates) the read words are located (at least some of them).

I have found that there are a market for "speech verification" services with this technology (automatically verifies that a recorded voice reads a specific text correctly and clearly) but I haven't found any software or lib/SDK which I can get the desired output from.

Can someone please give me insight in how good this kind of technology is and where I can find it? I'm interested in premium services, complete applications, libraries, SDKs - whatever make it work. Budget: unknown.

Edit: Support for big european languages are more or less required. English, French, German, Spanish, Greek, Italian, Russian, Polish would be nice but more are also welcome. This will probably be hard to accomplish...